# Will this relay handle my current and voltage requirements?

Tags: current, relay, datasheet

I have this relay: [SONGLE SRA-24vdc-cl](http://tec.org.ru/_bd/12/1208_SRA.pdf)

I want to use it to run 240V 11A device.

I can see in the datasheet it can be up to 20A (section 7, line 4-5), but the relay is so small and its legs so thin, so I am asking here before connecting it.

The 240V device should operate for 1 - 1.5 hours with 11 - 12A.

The coil is 24VDC, which I will use MOSFET to give it power (I have 300mA 24VDC adapter), and the gate will be connected to AVR MCU.

Comment: can you tell me please where did you saw that? when i am looking at the table i can see max current of 20A. should i look at the Contact Capacity instead?

Comment: Always look at the fine print. That 20A is under the most favorable circumstances, in this case 14V DC, resistive load. As I read the datasheet this relay is not rated for 240V AC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This relay is inappropriate for what you want to do.  You need to actually **read the datasheet**.  In the middle of the first page for #4, RATING, it clearly says 125 VAC.  Therefore 240 V is well out of spec.

[image]

What part of this is so confusing?

As for the current rating, if it says it's good for 20 A, then you can run 20 A thru it.  11 A would be fine, **if you weren't violating other specs**.

Comment: Funny.. i bought the relay as part of an electronic switch from China on Ebay, and they said it is good for 240VAC, but i guess you are right and they are not accurate with their info... it came like this case: http://www.dhgate.com/product/1-channel-315-433mhz-dc-9v-12v-24v-wireless/143437252.html

Comment: My remarks were directed at the OP and followed his comment.  I didn't name you or him.  @gabi - Does yours have "10A 250VAC" moulded/stamped into the top like the one in the photo? Upload a picture of your actual relay.

Comment: on the top it says 125V.. the whole Chinese business here is weird , so i asked here.. thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

The relay is rated (by the Chinese *manufacturer*) for 20A @ maximum 125VAC.

However, for some reason, UL does not believe that, they think it might just burst into flames at more than **10A/125VAC** (they don't care about functionality or life in the ratings, just about safety). A hint is that they only rate it for 10A at 14VDC, so it's probably getting too hot for their liking due to internal resistance.

So I **really** don't think it's good for 11A **or** 250VAC, and **certainly** not both together.

I tend to pay serious attention to safety agency ratings, particularly when the mains is involved. Think about defending your choice in a court of law after someone dies or their house burns down, and how such a choice is going to sound. "Well, I just picked the highest numbers I found. YOLO". This is *engineering* and we have a legal as well as a moral requirement to provide for the public safety.

Comment: @gabi No problem. There are also lots of fake UL markings and counterfeit parts made in China (I got burned for a ton of such product years ago), so all this is contingent on the markings being real. Songle **is** an established maker, but anybody can mark anything they want on a relay.

Answer (score 2):

Others have already commented along the lines of RTFM so I won't re-answer that.

However, for the sake of reliability you should usually take all data-sheet numbers (especially "headline" specs) with a pinch of salt. Doubly so when the device is a cheap no-brand one from eBay China.

I would normally over-spec things like relays, switches, cable, etc. by a factor of 10-50% in current handling - so if I know I need 20A current handling I would spec at least a 25A relay, and if there was no significant cost penalty I would spec up to 40A. I usually do this with car stuff, the highest spec "standard" car relays are 40A but 30A and lower spec are available. I just keep a box of 40A type as they cost pennies extra and you only need to keep one type.

A relay rated to 125v AC will probably not explode when used with higher voltages, but it may be electrically or thermally unsafe, unstable, unreliable, and have a much shorter life. Where mains is concerned, do not cut corners and ideally don't use the cheapest junk you can find. It only takes some brittle piece of low-spec plastic to crack on the relay body etc. to expose lethal voltages. Good quality safety-approved stuff costs more for a whole herd of good reasons.

Running stuff near the limit is rarely reliable as the marketing department applies quite a bit of optimism to most of the stuff in the data sheet, and the max rating in one column is not achievable at the same time as the max rating in another column, in fact usually the max ratings are extracted with all other conditions being engineered as close to "ideal" as possible. As stated above, the 20A rating will probably be at low voltage into an ideal load, and could be MUCH lower in non-ideal situations. Good manufacturers will at least give you this information in their data sheet, even if they don't make a big deal about it.